# How to quote Javadoc in thesis?

Tags: javadoc

I was wondering... Does anyone know how to quote official Oracle's javadoc in a thesis or research paper?

I am sorry if this is a little bit off topic for this site but I am sure this question may be important for a lot of programmers here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Although the question might be considered as off-topic (as it perhaps belogs rather [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)), an example for a suitable citation can be found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Cite-a-Website). Basically the documentation can be seen an online document or website, which means that is can be referenced as such. An important details different from publications on paper is the actual date of access to take into account the volatility of the document.